# node.js response buffering on node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am developing a node.js service that will have a number of requests per second - say 1000. Lets imagine that the response data weights a bit, connection with our clients is extremely slow and it takes ~1s for the response to be sent back to the client.

Question #1 - I imagine if there was no proxy buffering, it would take node.js 1000 seconds to send back all responses as this is blocking operation, isn't it?

Question #2 - How nginx buffers (and buffers in general) work? Would I be able to receive all 1000 responses to buffer (provided RAM is not a problem) and only then flush them the clients? What are the limits of proxy_buffers? Can I set a number of buffers to 1000 1K each?

The goal is to flush all the responses out of the node.js as soon as possible in order not to block it and have some other system to deliver them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, sending the response is non-blocking operation. Node simply gives a chunk to a network driver, leaving all the other work to your OS.

If sending the response was a blocking operation, it would only take a single PC with its network artificially crippled down to DoS any node-based service.